# How to run single command within shell script, but looping just the options

Tags: shell

suppose I want to loop over variables within shell script. However, it's not running command multiple times, but I want to run a single command, but want to avoid defining options many times.

Example is as below.

```
PORTS = {8080, 8081, 8082}
docker run -ti \
  for PORT in $PORTS:
    -p $PORT:$PORT
  --name sample-container
```

Comment: You want to run a command only once but change the options? Like in changing command options while it's already running?

Answer (score 0):

Take the whole command into the body of the loop:

```sh
for port in 8080 8081 8082
do docker run -ti -p $port --name sample-container
done
```